# Custom ArrayAdapter and Spinner. No item selection

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Android 1.6
There's a collection of such objects

```
public class MyItem {
public String name = "";
public String brief = "";
     public int availiableweight = 0; 
public Node xmlpoint = null;

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return name;
}
public MyItem(String _brief, String _name, Node _xmlpoint)
{
    name = _name;
    brief = _brief;
    xmlpoint = _xmlpoint;
}
 }
```

Objects were stored in array: ArrayList itemsList

Items are visible in dropdown list of spinner, but i cant select any item. Event  OnItemSelectedListener is not generated. Spinner control is empty. Where is my fault?

Code of application

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private ArrayList<MyItem> itemsList;
private Spinner mySpinner;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

    itemsList = new ArrayList<MyItem>();
    ArrayAdapter<MyItem> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, itemsList); 
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
    mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter); 

    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog("Pos: " + arg2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    itemsList.add(new MyItem("1","one",null));
    itemsList.add(new MyItem("2","two",null));
    itemsList.add(new MyItem("3","three",null));
}  
}
```

layout main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/languageText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Language" android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/languageSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:prompt="@string/chooseitem"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is over here:

```
ArrayAdapter<MyItem> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, itemsList);
```

You can't use the generic ArrayAdapter class since you have an array of custom objects. In the constructor for ArrayAdapter you use the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` layout file. but the adapter doesn't know how to display your data.

You have to use a custom Adapter and create your own XML layout file.
Read some examples on how to achieve this. It is best to understand how ListViews and adapters work.

See these links:

http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-i-basic-usage/

http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/

They provide a very good reference. You can go on reading the next parts of the 'Android Lists' series of tutorials to expand your knowledge.

Hope this helps. In case you need further explanation be sure to post a comment.

Answer (score 1):

thanks Bandreid for answer, but decision was another.
Don't use ArrayList directly, only through the adapter.
This code is correct

```
myAdapter.add(new MyItem("1","one",null));     
myAdapter.add(new MyItem("2","two",null));     
myAdapter.add(new MyItem("3","three",null));
```